# ngClass of undefined

Tags: angular, ng-class

I have the following

```
<h6 *ngSwitchCase="'text'" class="custom-popup-content-text">{{content.value}}</h6>
```

In my code, I pass sometime also a `content.className`, and want to add that class if the className is defined

I tried

```
<h6 *ngSwitchCase="'text'" [ngClass]="['custom-popup-content-text', content.className]">{{content.value}}</h6>

but this one doesn't work if classname is undefined
```

I tried also

```
<h6 *ngSwitchCase="'text'" [ngClass]="{'custom-popup-content-text' : true, content.className : content.className ? 'content.className' : ''}">{{content.value}}</h6>
```

but I got:
**Missing expected : at column 45** in

```
[{'custom-popup-content-text' : true, content.className : content.className ? content.className : ''}]
```

What I might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following :

```
<h6 *ngSwitchCase="'text'" [ngClass]="['custom-popup-content-text', ((content.className) ? content.className : '')]">{{content.value}}</h6>
```

Answer (score 0):

if that' the case define the class name and make it an empty class so that you can assign that empty class to it and get away with undefined error

Comment: the thing is that there is so much code using that generic template, and in very few case I want to add a custom class. Since I would like to not change every template call, I wanted a solution that works on undefined

Comment: then maybe try checking if the class is undefined then, move along to stop the crashing

Comment: template side there are no good ngClass trick to do that ? if so, yes I will go on and do the checking somewhere else.